# How to get the price information of a sale post in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, restfb

How can I get the price information of a sale post in Facebook? The following is my current code.

```
//Getting the facebook sale group's feed
Connection<Post> groupFeed = facebookClient.fetchConnection("xxxxxx/feed", Post.class,Parameter.with("fields", "from,message,picture"),Parameter.with("limit", 300));
for (List<Post> groupPosts : groupFeed) {
    for(Post groupPost:groupPosts){
        // TODO - to get the sale price of a sale post
    }
}
```

Comment: It is currently not possible

Comment: you have to parse the message. It seems it contains a title (up to 100 chars), the price, location and the optional description. It seems that there's a return after the title and a '-' before the location. Perhaps you can build a utility to split the message in the elements you can see in the input form. If my assumption is right, this should be possible. As admin of such a group you should have enough test data :)

Comment: Thanks Norbert.By the way,I really love restfb

Answer (score 0):

With fb api - impossible

But look in code - class `_l57` and thought of a simple script for CasperJS